# Spring security custom session timeout url

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Currently I'm working on spring security app, where I need user to be redirected to a custom lock page when session is expired which only contains a password field. (username might be placed in a hidden field inside the login form.) I need to pass username extracted from UserDetails instance and redirect to this custom URL once login session timed out.

I tried to use `concurrency-control -> expired-url` but it did not give me successful result.

I will be very helpful if you could give some guidence to achieve this.

Is this possible to achieve since I will need to have customized behavior on `authentication-failure-url` too? (when a given password is incorrect).

**Update 1:**
My current configuration:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd">

<http auto-config="true" create-session="always" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="authEntryPoint" >
    <form-login
            login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/home"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password"
            always-use-default-target="true"/>

    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/login" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>

    <session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession" invalid-session-url="/"
                        session-authentication-error-url="/login">
        <concurrency-control session-registry-alias="sessionRegistry" max-sessions="10"
                             expired-url="/lock-screen" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"/>
    </session-management>

    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasRole('ROLE_LOGIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/profile" access="hasRole('ROLE_LOGIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/home" access="hasRole('ROLE_LOGIN')"/>

    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="10"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="authEntryPoint" class="com.myapp.admin.security.web.authentication.AjaxSupportedLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
            scope="singleton">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="loginFormUrl" value="/login"/>
</beans:bean>
```

I'm expecting something like this:

user Login screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTPkF.png

Lock screen after logged in user being inactive for while:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY9kG.png

Comment: It did not redirect me to configured url ("/lock-screen") when session timed out. (expire session after being inactive to for a while)

Comment: It's like this. After session timed out I'm just redirecting to the default login page. Instead of that I want to redirect user to my custom lock screen page. (when user session is expired due to no interaction with the server for a while)

Comment: [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-concurrency-control-attributes) says: *The URL a user will be redirected to if they attempt to use a session which has been "expired" by the concurrent session controller because the user has exceeded the number of allowed sessions and has logged in again elsewhere.* A timed out (invalidate) session and a expired session are two different things.

Comment: Ah...Now I get it. So I can't get it done with this configuration. Thanks a lot @dur.

Comment: Is there any other way to get this done? may be by using some custom filter, listener or by something like that...

Comment: What done? The problem is that your `invalid-session-url` is not allowed. That is a bug in your configuration. You have to `permitAll` this URL, because a user with a session timeout is always anonymous.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot for the help. I will fix it. :)